# How to check if someone is liked my fanpage from my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-authentication

I want to check if a user liked my fan-page from my website and if he did i skip the step and if he didnt i want to suggest him to like my fan-page,its all on my website i dont want to put a landing page or something else on my fan-page.all of it is on my website,i don't want to put a landing page or anything else on my fan-page.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are only 2 ways for this:

<s>-) use the edge.create event: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/</s>

downside: this can only check right after clicking a like button on your website. so, if the user comes back, you can´t be sure if the like button is still clicked. also, you never get the id of the user, of course
(deprecated)

-) authorization with facebook login > you can check for the user likes > user_likes permission needed. but i doubt that you really want to authorize the user just for this...

the graph api call you could use:

```
me/likes?target_id=[page-id]
```

subscription:
permission user_subscriptions needed. graph api call would be the following:

```
me/subscribedto?user=[user-id]
```

Comment: graph api would be much easier, in a nice simple batch call :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need `user_likes` permission to view **like** information about the current session user.

refer to: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/user-friend-permissions/

then simply use fql to request information.

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=22934684677
```

If user likes the page graph will return id of page.
Example graph request like for page Facebook. 
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/135669679827333/?fql=SELECT%20page_id%20FROM%20page_fan%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme()%20AND%20page_id%3D20531316728

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "page_id": 20531316728
    }
  ]
}
```

Else array will be empty.

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Comment: this explorer helps me a lot, thanks