# How do I check if a user likes my page via facebook JS SDK nowadays?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been trying very hard to solve this issue for the last days, but I really can't get through. I've found this question many times on this forum, but none of the solutions presented here solved my problem because they have been posted some years ago and Facebook is updating the way to solve a given issue very often. My facebook javascript SDK to check if a user likes my page is as follows:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
        try {
            FB.init({
                appId  : '{my_app_id',
                status : true, // check login status
                cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                version: 'v5.0'
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
        try {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response['status'] == 'connected') {
                    try {
                        FB.api(
                            "/{my_page_id}/likes", {access_token: 'my_app_token'},
                            function (response) {
                              alert(response.error.message);
                              if (response && !response.error) {
                                //code to check likes
                              }
                            }
                        );
                    } catch (e) {alert(e.message);}
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }

    });
```

The FB.init works and also the FB.getLoginStatus, where response['status'] is really 'connected'. But my FB.api does not work. The alert(response.error.message); line returns the following error: "(#10) This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details.". I've been checking the manuals from Facebook for developers, but they are very incomplete, at least the ones in Portuguese (I am Brasilian). I'm really sick of trying to get this working by myself, so I'm looking for a help from the users of this forum.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The /page-id/likes endpoint returns likes of a Page (for example, other Pages liked by the Page), NOT users who like your Page. And for getting that data, you need to own the Page, and you need to authorize with the `manage_pages` permission.

There is no way to get a list of Users who like your Page, the only reliable way to check if a specific User likes a Page is by authorizing that User with the user_likes permission. After that, you can use the `/me/likes` endpoint to get liked Pages. Although, you would need to get the permission reviewed by Facebook, and you would need a very good reason to use the permission.

Additional Info: [How to check if someone is liked my fanpage from my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299616/how-to-check-if-someone-is-liked-my-fanpage-from-my-website/13101875#13101875)

Comment: Thank you, Iuschn. I started today the process of getting the user_likes permission, but as my business was being verified, I got this message: "Due to coronavirus (COVID-19), we have temporarily paused Individual Verification to focus our reviewers on efforts that help keep people informed and safe. We know this review step is important and will resume it as soon as we can.". I see that I will have to wait for a couple of months until I can get my issue solved.

Comment: You need to use FB.login for login/authorization, not FB.api: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/permissions